# How to run gradle based spring boot application in background using command line in ubuntu?

Tags: spring, hibernate

I am trying to run gradle based hibernate spring boot application in background thread.

Answer (score 3):

To run SpringBoot application with ubuntu as background application wia terminal, run below command

```
gradle clean build  -- TO CLEAN AND BUILD GRADLE APPLICATION
cd TO YOUR BUILD PATH(JAR FILE PATH)
java -jar YOUR_APP_JAR.jar &
```

Here "&" will assured that when you close your terminal, your application will not kill.

[check this for '&' usages in terminal](https://bashitout.com/2013/05/18/Ampersands-on-the-command-line.html)

Answer (score 1):

you can also run .war files in same way

```
> gradle clean build
> cd build/libs
> java -jar myApp.war &
```

Answer (score 0):

I use below to achieve this for one of the similar requirement.

```
nohup ./gradlew bootrun >application.log 2>&1 &
```

Answer (score -1):

Execute `gradle bootRun` in project directory if you have not packaged spring boot gradle application into a jar or war